# Task not garbage collected

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5

In the following program, I'd expect the task to get GC'd, but it doesn't. I've used a memory profiler which showed that the `CancellationTokenSource` holds a reference to it even though the task is clearly in a final state. If I remove `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion`, everything works as expected.

Why does it happen and what can I do to prevent it?

```
    static void Main()
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var weakTask = Start(cts);

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();

        Console.WriteLine(weakTask.IsAlive); // prints True

        GC.KeepAlive(cts);
    }

    private static WeakReference Start(CancellationTokenSource cts)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw new Exception(); });
        var cont = task.ContinueWith(t => { }, cts.Token, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.Default);
        ((IAsyncResult)cont).AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(); // prevents inlining of Task.Wait()
        Console.WriteLine(task.Status); // Faulted
        Console.WriteLine(cont.Status); // Canceled
        return new WeakReference(task);
    }
```

My suspicion is that because the continuation never runs (it doesn't meet the criteria specified in its options), it never unregisters from the cancellation token. So the CTS holds a reference to the continuation, which holds a reference to the first task.

**Update**

The PFX team has confirmed that this does appear to be a leak. As a workaround, we've stopped using any continuation conditions when using cancellation tokens. Instead, we always execute the continuation, check the condition inside, and throw an `OperationCanceledException` if it is not met. This preserves the semantics of the continuation. The following extension method encapsulates this:

```
public static Task ContinueWith(this Task task, Func<TaskStatus, bool> predicate, 
    Action<Task> continuation, CancellationToken token)
{
    return task.ContinueWith(t =>
      {
         if (predicate(t.Status))
              continuation(t);
         else
              throw new OperationCanceledException();
      }, token);
}
```

Comment: Debug / Release mode?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding Garbage Collection in .net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130382/understanding-garbage-collection-in-net)

Comment: Compounded by the task surely not yet being completed when the GC completes.

Comment: I've just checked... Task Finalizer is not being called... That is interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: I believe this is a memory leak (or two, see below) and you should [report it](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/).

Long answer:

The reason why the `Task` is not GCed is because it is reachable from the CTS like this: `cts` → `cont` → `task`. I think both of those references should not exist in your case.

The `cts` → `cont` reference is there because `cont` correctly registers for cancellation using the token, but it never unregisters. It does unregister when a `Task` completes normally, but not when it's canceled. My guess is the erroneous logic is that if the task was canceled, there is no need to unregister from the cancellation, because it had to be that cancellation that caused the task to be canceled.

The `cont` → `task` reference is there, because `cont` is actually `ContinuationTaskFromResultTask` (a class that derives from `Task`). This class has a field that holds the antecedent task, which is nulled out when the continuation is executed successfully, but not when it's canceled.

Answer (score -1):

as an addition...
In this case the Finalizer is being called:

```
WeakReference weakTask = null;
using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
{
  weakTask = Start(cts);
}

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();

Console.WriteLine(weakTask.IsAlive); // prints false
```

Comment: "The CTS is stored in a field for a long period." why?